# Alternative to GetMouseDown for multiple touches

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, touch

I have a game I am making in Unity3D, for Android, in which the player has two arrow buttons to press which control the characters movement left and right. If I click on the left arrow, I have to remove my finger to then press the right arrow and move right, as GetMouseDown does not recognise that these are two seperate touches.

Is there a better alternative to GetMouseDown that will recognise the most recently clicked arrow key for movement, so that I do not have to unclick the first arrow button, which is not very ergonomic

Comment: Sorry real fast what are you asking?  Do you mean you don't want the user to have to lift up their finger, and just slide their finger over, or you want it to only recognize the event if they lift their finger up and click again?

Comment: Sorry for ambiguity. Basically there are two buttons on the screen, if you click the left button, don't let go and then click the right button, it doesn't move the player in the right direction as it thinks that you only clicked left

Comment: Why not use [GetTouch](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetTouch.html), then you can save touch positions in array and access the most recent one.

Comment: Generally speaking `Input.GetTouch` is much preferred to the primarily mouse-oriented methods of getting input because of multi-touch concerns, but other than that you should post a snippet of your code since the behavior you're describing sounds a problem with possibly flawed logic rather than a problem with how you're getting input. Generally speaking `GetMouseDown` should aid in checking if a finger is down, but it won't tell you what's being pressed, you should be checking the position of the touch/click (usually with a raycast)